# Using of vue-router in the mixin

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuex

Here is my **component.vue**

```
<script>
  import dfsMixin from '@/mixins'

  export default {
    name: 'AppNavigation',
    props: {
      items: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
      }
    },
    mixins: [ dfsMixin ]
  }
</script>
```

Here is my **mixins/index.js**:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    routeToURL: (itemUrl) => {
      this.$router.push({ itemUrl })
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the mixin function called in the component template:

```
<v-list-tile v-else :key="item.text" @click="routeToURL(item.url)">
```

I receive the next error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

And here is my **this context in mixin**:

```
{a: {…}}
a
:
methods
:
routeToURL
:
ƒ routeToURL(itemUrl)
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
```

So how to use $route in mixin of the component?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
export default {
  methods: {
    routeToURL: (router, itemUrl) => {
      router.push({ itemUrl })
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
<v-list-tile v-else :key="item.text" @click="routeToURL($router, item.url)">
```

Comment: I've already tried, no effect :( In all I used @click=$router.push(item.url) construction, but absolutely can not understand why this.$router was inavailable nor just in mixin file, but also in component file.

Comment: @purple actually this.$router should be accessible through mixins. So the problem is somewhere else. Does the $router option work in other components? Does vue-devtools show the $route property of data object in the component?